# Moving averages

Tags: time-series, moving-average

I have 14 yrs monthly price of coconuts of a particular market. In order to identify the trend how do I know if I have to calculate 30 day, 60 day, 90 day, ... moving averages.

What is the basis for choosing the period? How do I compare the moving averages plotted for different periods?

Comment: If your data are monthly then moving averages will be based on months, presumably, so where 30, 60, ... days come in is not clear. Otherwise, some general guidelines are: 0. A strong trend won't need moving averages to be identified. Plot the data. 1. Think about what patterns you expect and what interest you. Here I would guess as well at a strong seasonal structure and possibly other structure too. 2. Plot the results  of smoothing to see the effects of different choices. 3. Think about the weighting structure of moving averages. You will need to read basic texts on time series too.