# Interpreting moving average chart

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, trend, moving-average

Using 26 years monthly price of coconuts I plotted the 2 period, 3 period and 4 period moving average charts. Every line seems to lie overlapped. What can I infer about the trend from this chart?

[image: Moving average chart]

Comment: What is the timespan of the "periods"? What do you want to infer / what are you trying to figure out about your data?

Comment: By 2 period I meant 2 months or 30 days moving average(approx) and likewise. How can I infer something about trend from this chart?

Comment: The above chart is called [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) or arima(0,1,0)+drift. There is no trend. Data such as price of commodities typically follow random walk.

Comment: This sounds familiar. Did you ask a question previously and then delete it? You are allowed to do that, but we may end up making very similar comments all over again. That's not a good use of the forum.

Comment: Yes. Actually I had not signed up completely and could not access it later.

Comment: Here is the cross-reference: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156767/moving-averages

Comment: There is clear rising trend but the proportional rise may not be as high for the last part of the curve since absolute value is increasing. What does time vs log(price) plot show? If it is interesting you can post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically no trend. The above data in the chart is called [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) or [random walk with drift](http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411rand.htm)/arima(0,1,0)+drift. There is no trend. Data such as price of commodities typically exhibit random walk behaviour.

Comment: Can you please explain what this really means?

Comment: The second link "random walk with drift" explains it very well.

Comment: So, this is a commodity price series that has resisted inflation over 26 years?

Comment: @NickCox, the drift in (0,1,0) with drift would be an average inflation.

Comment: @zbicyclist Thanks; I was focusing on "no trend".

Comment: Thank you. How do I choose the best ARIMA model?

Answer (score 1):

You have 26 years of monthly data.  Your largest window is 4 months (1/3 of a year).  That means you have 78 non-overlapping 4-month windows from start to finish.  If your chart were 10 cm wide, a 4-month window would be approximately 1.3 mm.  You are simply zoomed out too far to see anything on that scale.

Regarding what to infer, I suppose I would say that the large scale price fluctuations that are salient over these 26 years do not fluctuate appreciably within 4-month or smaller intervals.

Comment: I fitted a trend line to this chart in Excel and out of the options for linear, exponential, etc  it was found that the largest R^2 (0.667) is for a polynomial relation. Is this sounding sensible? for the sake of forecasting.

Comment: @user79826, no I doubt that is sensible. I would not use Excel to forecast this. Without meaning to sound snarky, I would not forecast here until you know a lot more about time series & forecasting.  Those are large topics; you will have to spend a good deal of time & effort to learn them. At that point, I would use some more sophisticated software than Excel to do your forecasting. Until then, you may need to work with a statistical consultant.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding moving average, suppose I take a larger period say 10. Does this sound better?